# Is every SQL undo when it never reaches the point of COMMIT?

Tags: mysql, sql

I think I got the principle right I just want to make sure I get it right.

So when autocommit is enabled it means every command I do wont be executed directly, except whose who trigger the commit themselves.
So when I've for example a basic macro running like:

```
statement.executeUpdate("SET autocommit = 0;")

//some code
//SQL Queries
//SQL DELETEs
//SQL INSERTs

statement.executeUpdate("COMMIT;")
```

Then what would happen would be - If the script runs through without any problem the script goes to the point where every SQL Statement is executed and COMMITed at the end, if not and an error or exception happens the script breaks at that point never turns to the point where the COMMIT is going to happen and every change prior to that point is undo, so that every deleted information will still be there and every insertion is thrown away.

Is it that simple or did I get something wrong?

Comment: That is how transactions work.  So, you are using them correctly.

Comment: Why not try and see what happens? ;)

Comment: If the `COMMIT` is not reached (due to an error or whatever), the transaction remains open. You should `ROLLBACK` to close the transaction.

Comment: @RobertKock Like having the ROLLBACK in something like a finally block?

Comment: @vMysterion more like a catch block. Finally is executed also in case of success

Comment: @RobertKock So going after the mentality "Rather one rollback too much than a commit"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a decent database, the data of the current transaction is not typically stored in the table heap itself but in a "redo log".

That is, it's not even in the table until the commit is executed. The commit and other later processed place them in the main table at some point.

In general, if the database engine crashes, the data may still be on disk somewhere, but not in any "official" table area, so it will be discarded when the database engine is restarted. It did not modify the actual data.